# WebCam image is flipped in Skype

Tags: skype, webcam

My WebCam image on Asus N61DA Laptop is flipped in Skype. Is working fine but flipped.
Also I can't push buttons in flash player for example to allow using my WebCam and Mic.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.  I have edited out your second question, feel free to ask a new question concerning it..  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If by "flipped" you mean left-to-right this is normal Skype behaviour.

If instead it is flipped upside-down then you may try loading Skype with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype`.